# pagination going to other link when clicking but counts the number of rows

Tags: php, sql, pagination

I have a problem with my pagination it's working but when I click for example

I have search ermel ermel has 8 fields and it's gonna output pagination
because limit is set to 5 per page

[1][2]

but when I click on the second page it will go to the other page and remove my query.

and will count my whole query again

[1][2][3][4][5][6]

like that and will reset to may default query

I'm not sure where the error is - I tried to remove some part but that's the only part that's not working properly thanks in advance .

Here's my working php code.

```
<?php
$searchtext = '';
if(isset($_GET['q'])) $searchtext = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']);
if($searchtext) {

  $per_page =5;
                        $pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('PersonID') FROM persons where firstname like '%$searchtext' or lastname like '%$searchtext' order by date desc ");
                        $pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query,0) / $per_page);

                        $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
                        $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

   $query=mysql_query("select * from persons where firstname like '%$searchtext' or lastname like '%$searchtext' order by date desc LIMIT $start,$per_page ");
} 

else 
{


   $per_page =5;
                        $pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('PersonID') FROM persons ");
                        $pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query,0) / $per_page);

                        $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
                        $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
    $query=mysql_query("select * from persons  order by date desc LIMIT $start,$per_page ");
}





    while($test = mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {
                $id = $test['PersonID'];

                                echo"<div class = content />";
                echo "<table>
                <tr>
                <td rowspan='2'><img height=200 width=200 src='upload/". $test['Image'] ."'/></td>
                <td><a href ='profile.php?PersonID=$id'>".$test['LastName'].", ". $test['FirstName']." ". $test['MiddleName']."</a>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href ='user_edit_reports.php?PersonID=$id'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Edit'/></a>
                </tr>
                </table>";

                                echo"</div>";



            }
                if ($pages >=1 && $page <= $pages) {
                           for ($x=1; $x<=$pages; $x++) {
                         echo ($x == $page) ? '<strong><a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.' </a></strong>' : '<a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.' </a>';
                           }
                         }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the links in the pagination do not include the search string part (`?q=...`), and so when you click them, you get the entire, unfiltered list again.

Comment: may i ask how to filter that in the  strong><a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.' </a></strong>? @Ulrich Schmidt-Goertz